# How can I make a whole card clickable?

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have 3 cards on my wordpress site homepage, [jookaskids.com.ng](https://jookaskids.com.ng), it has a link in it already, and I don't want only the link to be clickable but the whole card.

I hope my question is built well.

Example here on this bootstrap  page [HERE](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/stretched-link/)

[The Card Img Here](https://prnt.sc/vsg24u)

Comment: Questions that are just a bit more than a link to a website are off-topic here. The reason is that when a link gets obsolete, the question is no 

longer useful to future readers. We are trying to build a lasting repository of useful question/answer pairs 

here. Please read 
[**Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) 
as well as how to use this site in general
[**taking the tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole HTML structure of the card into an [`a` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) & specify corresponding `href` attribute.

Comment: How can I do that on wordpress, please?

Comment: Do you have control over your HTML or it is built using some builder (like WP Bakery or alike)?

Comment: it is WP Bakery

Comment: @NooblantisDistrict Then, inside column settings there should be an option called "Column link". Try to paste corresponding URL there.

Comment: can't find it 
https://prnt.sc/vshs0f
https://prnt.sc/vshsqd
https://prnt.sc/vshsx0
I also checked the column settings. It wasn't there